# Passing touch position to compute shader

Tags: unity, shaders, compute-shader

I am working on a game where I have to mix colored liquids as shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=11UFYyv8hjs&feature=youtu.be&t=316). I am working with [a plugin](https://github.com/keijiro/StableFluids) (StableFluids) to get this effect: [Effect](https://forum.unity.com/attachments/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f584c5a6c6332652e676966-gif.680976/)

**Problem:**

The shaders used in the plugin are able to create the effect I want but the effect is created in the wrong position; rather than being triggered at the point where the user’s finger is touching the screen, the effect is being triggered at other points.

**Implementation:**

The plug-in has one compute shader which takes 2 parameters: **force origin** and **force direction**. The force direction is working properly as the deformation happens in the direction of the finger swipe. However, I am having trouble the touch input position into an accurate force origin value. I am passing the force origin value to the shader using Unity’s "RaycastHit.textureCoord".

Below is the compute shader code:

```
// StableFluids - A GPU implementation of Jos Stam's Stable Fluids on Unity
// https://github.com/keijiro/StableFluids
 
#pragma kernel Advect
#pragma kernel Force
#pragma kernel PSetup
#pragma kernel PFinish
#pragma kernel Jacobi1
#pragma kernel Jacobi2
 
// Common parameter
float Time;
float DeltaTime;
 
// External force
float2 ForceOrigin;
float2 ForceVector;
float ForceExponent;
 
// U (velocity field)
Texture2D<float2> U_in;
SamplerState samplerU_in;
RWTexture2D<float2> U_out;
 
// W (velocity field; working)
Texture2D<float2> W_in;
RWTexture2D<float2> W_out;
 
// Div W
RWTexture2D<float> DivW_out;
 
// P (pressure field)
Texture2D<float> P_in;
RWTexture2D<float> P_out;
 
// Color map
Texture2D<half4> C_in;
SamplerState samplerC_in;
RWTexture2D<half4> C_out;
 
// Jacobi method arguments
float Alpha, Beta;
 
Texture2D<float> X1_in;
Texture2D<float> B1_in;
RWTexture2D<float> X1_out;
 
Texture2D<float2> X2_in;
Texture2D<float2> B2_in;
RWTexture2D<float2> X2_out;
 
// Advect step
[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void Advect(uint2 tid : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint2 dim;
    W_out.GetDimensions(dim.x, dim.y);
 
    float2 uv = (tid + 0.5) / dim;
    float2 duv = U_in[tid] * float2((float)dim.y / dim.x, 1) * DeltaTime;
 
    W_out[tid] = U_in.SampleLevel(samplerU_in, uv - duv, 0);
}
 
// Add-force step
[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void Force(uint2 tid : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint2 dim;
    W_out.GetDimensions(dim.x, dim.y);
 
    float2 pos = (tid + 0.5 - dim * 0.5) / dim.y;
    float amp = exp(-ForceExponent * distance(ForceOrigin, pos));
 
    W_out[tid] = W_in[tid] + ForceVector * amp;
}
 
// Setup for Project step (divW calculation)
[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void PSetup(uint2 tid : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint2 dim;
    W_in.GetDimensions(dim.x, dim.y);
 
    DivW_out[tid] = (W_in[tid + int2(1, 0)].x - W_in[tid - int2(1, 0)].x +
                     W_in[tid + int2(0, 1)].y - W_in[tid - int2(0, 1)].y) * dim.y / 2;
 
    P_out[tid] = 0;
}
 
// Finishing for Project step (divergence free field calculation)
[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void PFinish(uint2 tid : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    uint2 dim;
    W_in.GetDimensions(dim.x, dim.y);
 
    if (any(tid == 0) || any(tid == dim - 1)) return;
 
    float P1 = P_in[max(tid - int2(1, 0), 1)];
    float P2 = P_in[min(tid + int2(1, 0), dim - 2)];
    float P3 = P_in[max(tid - int2(0, 1), 1)];
    float P4 = P_in[min(tid + int2(0, 1), dim - 2)];
 
    float2 u = W_in[tid] - float2(P2 - P1, P4 - P3) * dim.y / 2;
 
    U_out[tid] = u;
 
    if (tid.x == 1) U_out[int2(0, tid.y)] = -u;
    if (tid.y == 1) U_out[int2(tid.x, 0)] = -u;
    if (tid.x == dim.x - 2) U_out[int2(dim.x - 1, tid.y)] = -u;
    if (tid.y == dim.y - 2) U_out[int2(tid.x, dim.y - 1)] = -u;
}
 
// Jacobi method with a scalar field
[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void Jacobi1(uint2 tid : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    X1_out[tid] = (X1_in[tid - int2(1, 0)] + X1_in[tid + int2(1, 0)] +
                   X1_in[tid - int2(0, 1)] + X1_in[tid + int2(0, 1)] + Alpha * B1_in[tid]) / Beta;
}
 
// Jacobi method with a vector field
[numthreads(8, 8, 1)]
void Jacobi2(uint2 tid : SV_DispatchThreadID)
{
    X2_out[tid] = (X2_in[tid - int2(1, 0)] + X2_in[tid + int2(1, 0)] +
                   X2_in[tid - int2(0, 1)] + X2_in[tid + int2(0, 1)] + Alpha * B2_in[tid]) / Beta;
}
```

Questions:

1. What kind of conversion is required to convert the touch input position to the shader’s coordinate system so that the effect appears where the finger has touched?
2. Are there any other open-source plug-ins to implement the required effect that have a clearer relationship between the touch input and the shader effect coordinates?

I would appreciate any suggestions and thoughts on this topic. Thank you.

Comment: You should show us 1) your code for capturing the touch position and sending it to the compute shader 2) images/videos/diagrams illustrating the current mapping you have between cursor position and force position, so we can find patterns that may give a clue as to what needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Get texture coordinate of touched position using "RaycastHit.textureCoord" method
2. That texture coordinate will be in the range from (0,0) to (1,1)
3. Convert that texture coordinates to the coordinates that shader can understand. (0,0) is the center of the screen and (0,0) is bottom left on texture. Using the basic lerp method, you can convert those coordinate systems.

Comment: This answer would be better if it demonstrated the code changes needed to convert the coordinates.